# Conflicting routes in ASP.NET Core when using Attribute based routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

## Context

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core web API controller that will expose the following methods with specific semantics:

**/api/experimental/cars** *— get entire collection*

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/")]
public Task<List<Car>> AllCars()
```

**/api/experimental/cars/123** *— get car by id "123"*

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{carId}")]
public Task<Car> CarById([FromRoute] string carId)
```

**/api/experimental/cars?nameFilter=Maz** *— get cars that match nameFilter = "Maz"*

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{nameFilter?}")]
public Task<List<Car>> CarsByNameFilter([FromQuery] string nameFilter = "")
```

**/api/experimental/cars?nameFilter=Maz&rating=2** *— get cars that match nameFilter = "Maz" and with rating greater or equal to 2*

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{nameFilter?}/{rating?}")]
public Task<List<Car>> CarsByNameAndRatingFilter([FromQuery] string nameFilter = "", [FromQuery] int rating = 1)
```

**Note**: I really want to keep the controller class clean and have a single method per Web API route — is it possible?

## Problem

As you could guess, there's an issue with these API definitions. Basically, AllCars is intercepting pretty much all the requests. (When I was able to get at least the `/api/experimental/cars/{carId}` working, the query-string based APIs were still not working and intercepted by another method...

I tried many possible route syntaxes to express what I want with no luck. Is it even possible to use the default routing mechanism or I need to implement my own Router class or Middleware or something else?

## Update 1: Problem definition

I know I can join at least three methods and their routes into a single WebAPI method that is being smart about the received parameters. Notice that this is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Why?

Reason 1: I saw that in non-.NET routers, it worked well and there's no technical impossibility to implement semantic based route resolution.

Reason 2: I perceive all four URL patterns mentioned above as four different routes. One may not agree with me and it's okay, but for my purposes the methods and the routes are different and have to stay different.

Reason 3.1: This keeps controller code **clean**. Every method only handles one specific case. Parameter names are sufficient to properly resolve the routes (at least in humans head, therefore machine can do it too -- it's easy to formalize the algorithm). If client make a request with an unsupported query parameter, it should result in `HTTP 404 Not Found` or `HTTP 400 Bad Request` -- totally fine (client rather construct correct URLs).

Reason 3.2: On contrary, if I join the methods and use a more generic route, my implementation needs to be 'smart' about the combination of parameters. This is effectively, a leak of routing abstractions into a layer where it does not belong in my architecture. Complex validation is another thing I don't want to see in the Controller -- less code is better.

## Update 2: Nancy — Another .NET example (other that .NET Core WebApi)

There is Nancy (a .NET framework) which perfectly deals with this aspect of routing: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern  The issue is that in my project we're not using it... Nancy works as a perfect example of a tool that leaves exact definition of routing semantics to the client, instead of enforcing too tight rules on *what is the route* vs *what is not*.

Comment: The optional routes parameters are the cause of your problems

Comment: Is the car id alpha numeric or numeric only?

Comment: @nkosi I understand where the problem comes from. :) The car Id is string, not a number.

Comment: Does it follow a pattern where you can apply a constraint to uniquely identify it when routing.

Comment: If you are talking about /api/experimental/cars/123, then yes. This one locates a car with id "123" (which may or may not exist).

Comment: @Nkosi See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with this topic tells me that the best way to implement the APIs I wanted is to have two methods:

```
class CarsController {

    // [HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/")]
    [HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{carId}")]
    public Task<IEnumerable<Car>> CarById([FromRoute] string carId)
    {
        if (carId == null)
            return GetAllCars();
        else
            return GetCarWithId(carId);
    }

    // [HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{nameFilter?}")]
    [HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{nameFilter?}/{rating?}")]
    public Task<IEnumerable<Car>> CarsByNameAndRatingFilter([FromQuery] string nameFilter = "", [FromQuery] int rating = 1)
    {
        // TODO Validate the combination of query string parameters for your specific API/business rules.
        var filter = new Filter {
            NameFilter = nameFilter,
            Rating = rating
        };
        return GetCarsMatchingFilter(filter);
    }

}
```

The first API is almost trivial. Even though returning a single item within a wrapping collection object may not look nice, it minimizes the number of API methods (which I personally am fine with).

The second API is trickier: in a way, it works as the [façade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). I.e. that API will respond to pretty much all the possible `/api/experimental/cars?` based routes. Therefore, we need to very carefully validate the combination of received arguments before doing the actual work.

Answer (score 1):

You could Achieve this with just two routes:

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/")]
public Task<List<Car>> SearchCars([FromQuery] string nameFilter = "", [FromQuery] int rating = 1)
```

and

```
[HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/{carId}")]
public Task<Car> CarById([FromRoute] string carId)
```

I.e one route which brings the entire set back but can be filtered accordingly and one the brings back a single Car object by Id.

You will notice that the SearchCars method doesn't include the parameters in the route, FromQuery will catch these anyway.

EDIT:
if your request becomes complex it can be nice to define a custom request object type to wrap all your filters together:

```
public class MyRequestObject
{
    public string NameFilter {get;set;}
    public int Rating {get;set;}
}
```

then:

```
   [HttpGet("/api/experimental/cars/")]
   public Task<List<Car>> SearchCars([FromQuery] MyRequestObject requestParams)
```

Comment: I understand I could use two different routes instead of four, but that will make the implementation heavier. I really don't want that -- I want the API implementation to be thin and to the point. My question explicitly restricts the solution to four independent routes and methods. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: I think it is important to make the distinction between route values a query parameters here. With the four routes you define there is ambiguity. The routes: ...api/cars and ...api/cars?nameFilter=something are the same route "api/cars" to have a different route the url would look like: api/cars/someFilter. this is a new route because "/" denotes a new parameter - but I'm assuming you wanted the url more readable, which is why I suggested what I did - it fits your requirements for having the right Urls and I believe it is the cleanest, if not the only way.

Comment: Further... consider also the the two routes you tried with optional parameters. if these are not provided then there is a problem with having an ambiguous routes.  i.e. /api/experimental/cars/{nameFilter?} without the parameter provided is /api/experimental/cars/ which you have already defined

Comment: `The routes: ...api/cars and ...api/cars?nameFilter=something are the same route "api/cars"` -- that is highly arguable and really depends on perception. I don't see these arguments to be necessarily the same, they may or may not be depending on API.

Comment: `Further... consider also the the two routes you tried with optional parameters. if these are not provided then there is a problem with having an ambiguous routes.` -- there is no ambiguity if an unsupported argument is provided. `HTTP 404 Not Found` is the way to react. If a supported argument is provided, its name should be used for method/route resolution. I see that you're trying to justify why .NET limits me/how I can work it around, but my question is not about a work around. My question is specifically about four methods and related routes. Please, don't twist the problem definition.

Comment: No. In terms of Routing they are the same. That is fundamental. I'm telling you this because I do not believe having the four routes is possible - because, as I have said, they are *two* different routes one of which has query parameters. As an alternative, maybe look at my edit with the request object?

Comment: could you please point me to a document that supports your claim about the `same routes`? I may be wrong, but at this point I don't see it.  `In terms of Routing` -- is it in terms of .NET WebAPI Routing? Or RESTful APIs? Or HTTP semantics?

Comment: go to any Website in the world in your browser, and add a query. Ie. Stackoverflow.com/?myparameter=test you'll notice that the page stays on stackoverflow.com. you do not get a 404. It's the same route, with a different query

Comment: MS Documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing

Comment: We're not discussing web sites, we're discussing the RESTful APIs. That may treat the URL with and without parameters as same or different routes.

Comment: @Nkosi  Your link points to .NET specific implementation, therefore it's not very authoritative about the Routes as a general concept known in RESTful services. As I said, I may be very very wrong thinking about the routes the way I think now, but I'd love to see HTTP protocol based or RESTful services paper based materials that explain the routes I show in my question are the same.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko You are trying to apply a general concept on a very .Net specific implementation. what you want will not work with the present iteration of the framework without making changes to how to uniquely differentiate the routes. From a framework perspective your route templates will conflict with each other because the are the same.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks! That is exactly what I was hoping to hear (if not a working solution itself). I was hoping it is possible to use this framework to serve my needs. It is unfortunate to see this limitation though because my code will probably get more tangled that I want it to be. Thanks for stressing, the **framework** perspective on routes.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko what you want can happen with some changes to your route templates but it looks like you a dead set on a specific pattern. Cannot fault you for that if those are your requirements. That is why I was inquiring about the possibility of applying route constraints to the templates .

Comment: I too appreciate the desire to separate them out, I've tried it myself - that is why I'm here. Reading into it though honestly wouldn't call it a limitation, the behaviour is there to conform to the standard of urls.

Comment: @MartinMilsom I do see it as a limitation, because there is a library (implemented in .NET) which does not restrict us in the way .NET WebAPI does -- see my Update 2 above. I also, don't believe that there is a standard on URL interpretation as routes. This is exactly why there are so many arguments on what is RESTful, what is not RESTful, and what is not so RESTful. Route is not really a concept of HTTP as I understand, but a concept of a tool that maps URLs to their handlers. As we see, different tools approach this mapping problem differently..

Comment: @MartinMilsom thanks for your proposal. I upvoted your solution. Even though it's not what I was looking for, it may be very helpful for somebody who faces the same trouble and has softer restrictions.

Comment: Yes, different tools map routes differently i Perhaps went piste when discussing the fundamentals off urls, I thought it would help explain why routes are handled this way in asp.net. sure, Nancy can use what they call constraints on routes. When talking about your example I perhaps should of used the phrase "same location" not "route" as that confused matters. Asp maps a location to an action. Anything to the right of a '?" In the url is part of the query, not the location. Servers/frameworks/ coders interpret the query how they like. Locations should behave consistently

Comment: ... that was why I suggested checking the website. Because it's how urls work, regardless whether it is a restful api or a website serving html. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL but again that may be a little off track to your question, I just think it helps understand why WebApi works this way and why I think it is good behaviour, not necessarily a limit. Anyway, glad Nkosi helped and you have an answer- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following suggested routes that when tested do not conflict with each other and still allow for all the actions to be segregated.

```
[Route("api/experimental/cars")]
public class CarsController : Controller {

    //GET api/experimental/cars
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult AllCars() { ... }

    //GET api/experimental/cars/123
    [HttpGet("{carId}")]
    public IActionResult CarById(string carId) { ... }

    //GET api/experimental/cars/named/Maz 
    //GET api/experimental/cars/named?filter=Maz 
    [HttpGet("named/{filter?}")]
    public IActionResult CarsByNameFilter(string filter = "") { ... }

    //GET api/experimental/cars/filtered?rating=2&name=Maz 
    //GET api/experimental/cars/filtered?rating=2 
    //GET api/experimental/cars/filtered?name=Maz 
    [HttpGet("filtered")]
    public IActionResult CarsByNameAndRatingFilter(string name = "", int rating = 1) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this variant. I know it's a working solution, but the syntax for `cars/named?filer=...` and the one for `/cars/filtered` is a thing I am trying to avoid. Query parameters directly applied to the resource name (`cars`) would look way more natural and expressive.

I read `cars/named?filter=...` as an address to a named collection of objects. The issue is that there is no such resource in fact. There is a resource `cars` but not `cars/named`. The latter is a virtual entity which is not truly a part of the business domain.

Comment: As I understand now, my problem definition does not have an .NET WebAPI based solution that would satisfy every single requirement point. As a result, our team will probably stick to the approach you described even though I find it way less expressive compared to the desired one. Please update your answer with an explicit note that this can not be achieved in the requested form. I will wait for a couple of days and mark your answer as an accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko has this been resolved. Following up.